# Add font to custom Android TextView

Tags: android, jar, components

I could create an Android custom TextView with red background,  and I exported it as a Jar file .
(I followed this [link](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/details/plugins-and-jars) )

So I added that jar file to an another project and it is fine .

But when I add a custom font to TextView , that font doesn't exists in exported jar file !
So I get an error because android could not find my font .

How can I create a full custom component (UI and JAVA) and export it as JAR file?

Comment: You can publish an [Android library module](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html#CreatingAModule) as an AAR file, which will contain your JAR plus assets, resources, and a manifest.

Comment: could you refer me to a good tutorial ?

Comment: Thanks, I finally could create an AAR and add it to project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could create an AAR and add it to project.

Comment: How did you do it? Show us an example and some code so that it can help people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use fonts which are used for example in windows `(.TTF)` you should do as following:

1- create a folder named "font" in ASSETS
2- copy your font file there
3- in java activity file:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/FONTNAME.TTF");
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
}
```